# SQL Server Extract INTs from VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this looks like a duplicate, but I don't see the answer I'm looking for yet.

I have an ID column that is VARCHAR(36) for ID tokens. In a legacy system, these tokens are only INT. Now they are all mixed up, and I need to be able to extract only the integer tokens for certain operations, and they have to be converted to INTs.

I thought I could do that by this:

```
select top 100000 convert(int,CustomerToken) as CustomerToken
from Customer
WHERE (CustomerToken NOT LIKE '%[^-+ 0-9]%' AND CustomerToken < '214783647')
```

But there are some numeric values that I don't want. But some numeric values give problems. I get the error varchar value '11122241333' overflowed an int column.

This seems really odd to me. This seems even weirder:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE '11122241333' < '2147483647'

1
```

????

Has anyone seen this before? Anyone know what I can do about it?

Comment: Convert to bigint or decimal instead.

Comment: change your int to a long to fix your first issue.  Also, try: SELECT 1 WHERE 11122241333 < 2147483647.  That's how SQL is designed to work, in a string comparison 2 > 1 so it returns 1.

Comment: Answer is above...explanation for current behaviour...ever see a list go 1,10,11,2,20,3,4,5,6,etc...?  It's the way varchar numbers are sorted.

Comment: Okay. I understand the behavior now. Thank you for that. But I can't convert to bigint to get around this. Result has to be INT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to "LPAD" your strings (I choose 20 as max length, which is of course arbitrary), if you want a "pseudo-number" comparison.

```
select top 10000 convert(int, CustomerToken) as CustomerToken
from Customer
WHERE (CustomerToken NOT LIKE '%[^-+ 0-9]%' 
AND replicate('0', 20- len(CustomerToken)) + CustomerToken < '0000000000214783647')
```

Comment: First example throws: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Second example works a treat. Thank you! Also, I'd not seen replicate before. Good to know about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or later then you can use `try_parse()`.

```
SELECT TOP 100000 try_parse( CustomerToken as int ) AS CustomerToken
```

If the value cannot be cast then the function will return a null marker, otherwise it will return an int.